# CMS with SSO, cloud support, i18n

Tags: cms, cloud-service, cloud-storage

I'm looking for a CMS that would have the following

- SSO - with oauth/jwt/openid, cool if it supports keycloak directly
- cloud support - storage / cdn / scalable
- i18n - multi language
- multi platform support - eventually

Open-source, free of charge solutions have an obvious advantage, but that's not a must.

Comment: For Cloud support, what do you mean? That it should be able to run in a Cloud (such as AWS) or that it should be a SaaS offering?

For multi-platform support, are you speaking of client-side (end users) or the server-side?

Are you thinking more of an Enterprise File Sync and Share app (such as Dropbox) or an Enterprise Content Management System (that supports metadata, records management or something more like Drupal?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for your comment. Cloud support would be mostly that it can scale on demand to respond to traffic picks and it's deployable in Cloud (so any cluster / replication mechanism that will support you when it comes to scalability). For example Magnolia offers limited SSO (LDAP, NTLM) and some cloud support hence it's not a full match, and the EE support is very expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among all the CMS platforms, I'd go with Wordpress, possibly WP multisite if you are considering a network.

It scales nicely - a few really big newssites run on it - for your perusal: https://wordpress.org/showcase/tag/newspaper/

It has a plugin / app store like no other CMS
SSO for multisite: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multisite-sso/

Keycloak: https://wordpress.org/search/keycloak

Multilanguage: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilanguage/

You name it, it probably exists.

However my two key reasons to choose WP would be:

- Huge userbase guarantees that bugs are caught and fixed real quick.
- I can host it and run it anywhere I please and do not necessarily need a team of devs to tweak it.